# How do I create a shortcode to display the terms of a Custon Taxonomy with their images in a page section?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am a novice at WordPress (and PHP actually) and need help displaying the terms of a custom taxonomy (Countries) in a page section being built with Elementor. The ideal situation would be to display each term under the term image in a row of three columns (each column having a term and image). The idea is to click on a taxonomy image (term image) and be sent to a page displaying all the post types in that taxonomy term.

The custom taxonomy was created using the Custom Post Type plugin and the images attached to the terms by creating a custom field for the taxonomy using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. The route I am going is to create a shortcode file with the required code (countries.php) and register it in my functions.php file. So I can use the shortcode directly in an Elementor column to display the taxonomy terms.

The shortcode file (countries.php)

```
<?php

function countries()
{
    $terms = apply_filters('taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'countries',
    ));
    if (
        !empty($terms)
    ) {
        $i = 1;
        print '<div class="elementor-row">';
        foreach ((array) $terms as $term) {
            print '
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element" data-element_type="column">
                    <div class="text-center p-3">
                        <div>
                            <a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($term, $term->taxonomy)) . '">
                                <img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image($term->image_id, 'ib') . '">
                            </a>
                        </div
                        <p class="sl-text mt-3">' . get_terms() . '</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>';
            if ($i % 3 == 0) :
                '</div>
                <div class="elementor-row">';
            endif;
            $i++;
        }
        print '</div>';
    }
}

add_shortcode('countries', 'countries');
```

Registering the shortcode file in the functions.php file

```
require_once('shortcodes/countries.php');
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I will be happy to provide further information if required. Thanks!!!

Attached is a snapshot of what I am trying to achieve (area circled in red).

[Image of page section showing the display I am trying to achieve (column beside the large text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brYSS.png)

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: I need help in creating a shortcode to display all the terms of a taxonomy along with their images. I want to insert the shortcode in a page section in Elementor.